# SSAS with SSRS drilldown

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report that displays totals per weekending for last 10 weeks per clinician. The report has week ending as column group and clinician as row groups. But my second report which is the details drilldown report on week ending should display all the days in that week and display data.

```
Clinician   Week1   Week2   Week3
--------------------------------------
Clinician1   10      25      35
Clinician2   23      40      112
.....
.....
.....
```

in the above sample each one of the totals under week1, week2 or week3 is a drilldown to details report. This drill down works but when i need to show all the weekdays even if there is no data for that clinician. Right now i can only able to show those days in a particular week that has data. Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Count of ID] } ON COLUMNS, { ([Data].[ClinicianName].[ClinicianName].ALLMEMBERS * [Data].[FacilityName].[FacilityName].ALLMEMBERS * [Data].[FacilityID].[FacilityID].ALLMEMBERS * [Data].[WeekEnd].[WeekEnd].ALLMEMBERS * [Data].[FullWeekName].[FullWeekName].ALLMEMBERS * [Data].[DateNumber].[DateNumber].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DataFacilityID, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DataClinicianID, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DataWeekEnd, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Model]))) WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@DataClinicianID, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@DataClinicianID, CONSTRAINED), [Data].[ClinicianID].currentmember ) ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually end up using linked server with stored proc and it works like a charm and the performance is good because i basically filter the data from cube.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MDX query builder in SSRS, there's a button to "show empty cells"...
[image]

...or if you are manually constructing the MDX, just remove the NonEmpty function...

Comment: Yes i am using MDX i did not that still not showing for a particular clinician which do not have data for a weekday. I need to show all the days in selected week.

Comment: I see in my data i dont see saturday and sunday weekday since we dont have data but how can i display those two days, i tried linked server mdx with stored proc but it is really slowly because i am pulling all data as i do not have luck with parameters in mdx query with openquery

Comment: This is in sql 2012 tabular model

Comment: ahhh gotcha...the design concept of breaking out your date data into a separate table is still valid.  See this post...it's geared toward PowerPivot but is equality applicable to Tabular models in regards to the numbered rules